# condition of potentially good reduction of representations

Tags: representation-theory, galois-representations

Let $l, p$ be distinct primes and let $K$ be a local field of mixed characteristic $(0,p)$. Let $G=G(K^s/K)$, $I_K$ be the inertia subgroup and $V$ a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Q_l$ with a continuous representation $\rho:G \to GL(V)$. The condition of $V$ having potentially good reduction is defined by the condition that $I_K \subseteq \textrm{ker}\,\rho$.
I need to show that this condition is equivalent to there being a finite extension $K'$ of $K$ inside $K^s$ such that as $\rho(I_{K'})$ is trivial.

I am unable to see either direction.

Comment: As stated this "equivalence" is false, so I'm not surprised you're having trouble proving it.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Could you please check my argument below? I saw the definition and equivalence in Fonaine-Ouyang, page 11.

Answer (score 0):

The direction $\rho(I_K)< \infty \implies \rho(I_{K'})=1$ for a finite extension:

$\rho(I_K)< \infty$ means that $I_K \cap \textrm{ker}\rho$ has finite index in $I_K$. But we also have $I_K \cap \textrm{ker} \rho$ as a closed subset of $I_K$, hence is open in $I_K$. Therefore there is an open set $G_{K'}=G(K^s/K')$ of $G_K$ given by a finite extension $K'/K$ such that $I_K \cap G_{K'} \subseteq I_K \cap \textrm{ker} \rho$. But $I_K \cap G_{K'}=I_{K'}$ and by the above containment we have $\rho(I_{K'})=1$.

The reverse direction:

But since $G_{K'}$ has finite index in $G_K$, $I_{K'}$ has finite index in $I_K$. By the condition $\rho(I_{K'})=1$, we have $I_{K'} \subseteq \textrm{ker}\rho \cap I_K \subseteq I_K$. So $[I_K: \textrm{ker}\rho \cap I_K]= \rho(I_{K})< \infty$.

Comment: For the first implication, you should probably justify why any open subgroup of $I_K$ is the intersection with $I_K$ of an open subgroup of $G_K$; since $G_K / I_K$ is infinite, this is not entirely obvious.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler But I have not claimed that the open set in question is equal to $I_K \cap G_{K'}$. Mere containment is sufficient.

Comment: Containment is indeed sufficient. How do you justify this containment?